# Глобальное нажатие на кнопки во vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Доброго времени суток.

Не могу найти инфо, о том, как можно отслеживать нажатие на клавиши.

Что я имею ввиду:

```
$('html').keydown(function(e){ //отлавливаем нажатие клавиш
  if (e.keyCode == 13) { //если нажали Enter, то true
    alert("Ура нажали Enter");
  }
});
```

Вот пример кода на jquery как мы могли отслеживать глобальное нажатие на enter, как можно подобное организовать на vue?

Спасибо

Comment: просто на корневом компоненте объявить событие `@keyup.enter`

Comment: @etki ну такое) не получается, я б не задавал вопрос если б так получилось) Если повесить на инпут событие, то все работает, но мне интересно на все окно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

Придумал как запилить такую штуку, пора уже покупать себе уточку и ей задавать вопросы :)

Вот таким макаром решил:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    created() {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown)
    },

    beforeDestroy() {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown)
    },

    methods: {
        onKeyDown(e) {
            console.log('keydown!');
            console.log(e.target);
        }
    },
});
```

Суть в том, что вьюха уже сама себе забиндила клавиши и нужно сначала удалить ивент, а потом добавить свой.

Comment: Выходит что своего решения у Vue.js нет? Это же по сути мешает  сохранить чистоту логики и абстрагироваться от деталей реализации событий DOM...